# Android Saving A Sharedpreferences Array

Tags: java, android, google-maps, for-loop

I'm currently trying to store google map markers with sharedpreferences on onPause and onResume. I have an array with default values declared for testing. When I load and place the markers I don't seem to get anything other then the default value I put in of 0.0. Did I mess up a for loop some where maybe? Or am I overlooking something completely?

Here are my two methods.

```
@Override
public void onPause(){


    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    //public double listOfPoints[];

    int length = listOfPoints.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){


    //Save each GPS value
    editor.putString(Integer.toString(i), Double.toString(listOfPoints[i]));

    //Save how many data points we had
    editor.putString("length", Integer.toString(length));

    editor.commit();
    }

    //Double.parseDouble() and Double.toString()
}





@Override
public void onResume(){

    super.onResume();
    //Load array of data back into the array
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Get the number of GPS points (1GPS location is 2 points)
    int length = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString("length", "0"));


    //Get all the GPS points into an array
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){

    listOfPoints [i] = Double.parseDouble(sharedPreferences.getString("i", "0.0"));

    }




    loadMarkers();
}

private void loadMarkers() {


    //Add markers onto the map
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfPoints.length; i = i + 2){
    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(listOfPoints[i], listOfPoints[i+1])).title("Default"));

    }
    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0.0, 0.5)).title("hats"));
    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(1.0, 0.5)).title("hats2"));
}
```

Comment: 1) Think I would construct a single Bundle of data in the for loop and store that one object instead 2) sounds as a rather expensive operation to do in onResume and onPause, would it not make sense to move it to onSaveInstanceState and onCreate?

Comment: try to print value in log before store in sharepreference,make sure you didn`t get null value.

Comment: Since last night I've used log tags to see how the data is being stored and loaded. (I've even switched the codes into onclick methods for testing) The most problems where in the loading method. The numbers for the loops where just off a little, and the below problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getString(Integer.toString(i), "0.0")` instead of `getString("i", "0.0")` because 1,2,3,.. is key instead of `i` :

```
listOfPoints [i] = Double.parseDouble(
                   sharedPreferences.getString(Integer.toString(i), "0.0"));
```

Comment: It might be the answer.

Comment: Thanks, This was defiantly part of the problem. I have also found that in                            `for(int i = 0; i < listOfPoints.length; i = i + 2){
    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(listOfPoints[i], listOfPoints[i+1])).title("Default"));

    }` length of the array isn't the stored length. This has been fixed with `leng = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString("length", "null"));` Still not working 100% right though.